# Encrypt a string

Tags: c, arrays, string, for-loop

I'm writing a program that encrypts a given string in this manner:

If we have an integer V and an array of only vowels v={a,e,i,o,u} if the letter of the string is a vowel then substitute it with the vowel that comes before it by V positions considering only the array of vowels (not the whole alphabet!).

To be clear:

```
String: "uuuu" and V:2 -----> String_out: "iiii"
String: "aaaa" and V:2 -----> String_out: "oooo"
String: "iiii" and V:2 -----> String_out: "aaaa"
```

So to solve my problem I wrote:

```
    V=2;
    char vow[5]={'a','e','i','o','u'};
    for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++){
        flag=0;
    for(j=0;j<5 && flag==0;j++){
        if(*(s+i)==vow[j]){
            flag=1;
    }
        if(flag)
           *(s+i)=vow[j-V%5];
    }
```

The code takes each element of the string the verifies if it is a vowel, then if it is a vowel substitute the considered element of the string with the vowel that comes before V positions.

This code works if the string has only the vowels **i,o,u** but if it has **a,e** the output will be wrong :
PROBLEM

```
char vow[5]={'a','e','i','o','u'};
j=1 // it will happen if the string is "eeee" in fact corresponds to 'e' in vow
V=2
vow[j-V%5]=... // j-V%5 is a negative number!!!!
```

So how can I solve my problem also for the letters a and e  so that I will no longer obtain negative numbers in vow[...] and respect correctly the encription rules? 
Please tell me if something is not clear and thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This code works if the string has only the vowels i,o,u but if it has a,e the output will be wrong :

- This happens because when vowel is `a` or `e`, `j-V%5` is *negative*(since, j is `0` or `1`) *as you have rightly mentioned*.

  ```
  //when j=0 i.e, vowel `a`
  j-V%5 = 0-(2%5) = -2 //`%` has more priority over `-`

  //when j=1 i.e, vowel `e`
  j-V%5 = 1-(2%5) = -1
  ```
- Just use `(5 + j- (V % 5)) %5` instead to avoid negative index value of `vow[]` array

  ```
  //when j=0 i.e, vowel `a`
  (5+j- (V%5))%5 = (5+0-(2%5))%5 = 3

  //when j=1 i.e, vowel `e`
  (5+j- (V%5))%5 = (5+1-(2%5))%5 = 4

  //when j=2 i.e, vowel `i`
  (5+j- (V%5))%5 = (5+2-(2%5))%5 = 0    

  //when j=3 i.e, vowel `o`
  (5+j- (V%5))%5 = (5+3-(2%5))%5 = 1

  //when j=4 i.e, vowel `u`
  (5+j- (V%5))%5 = (5+4-(2%5))%5 = 2
  ```

This would help you avoid negative indexing of the `vow[]` array

---

One more way to do it is to,

- after assigning value to`V` make `V = (V % 5) + 5`
- Now, you could use `(V -j)%5` as the index

Comment: It should be  V%5 in the parenthesis because if V=70 the output would be wrong. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: ya v%5 in the parenteses and then again %5

Comment: I just put V=2 to fix the ideas but it supposed to be a generic number

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that for a and e, you are supposed wrap around so the a->o and e->u

Change this

```
j-V%5
```

to

```
((j-V%5) + 5) % 5
```

**Example**

```
V=2, j=1

j-V%5 ---------------> -1
(j-V%5) + 5 --------->  4
((j-V%5) + 5) % 5 --->  4

Result:
'e' --> 'u'
```